# How to set date command line output defaults to 24h format?

Tags: 20.04, date

My XFCE shows correct time:

[image: XFCE4 date]

But when running `date` command it defaults to 12h format?

[image: date from command line]

already tried solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188019/112428) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553679/set-clock-to-24-hour-format-for-all-users) question but still the same, I'm using `en_CA.UTF-8` btw.

Comment: Are you sure it's the format that is incorrect? if it was really 12h format, I'd expect an AM/PM indicator. What does `echo $TZ` say? what do you get if you set the TZ explicitly ex.  `TZ='Asia/Jakarta' date` ?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, it is 12h format, since if it was 24h format, it should be 21:51 not 09:51

Comment: @steeldriver `echo $TZ` is empty, when `TZ='Asia/Jakarta' date` it shows the same as `date`

Answer (score 1):

you might be lucky after reading about the `LC_` variables , `timedatectl` and:

- [How To change timezone](https://vitux.com/how-to-change-the-timezone-on-your-ubuntu-system/)
- [How to change thedefault timezone with LC_TIME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064167/how-can-i-change-the-default-date-format-using-lc-time)
- [Ubuntu time manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime)

Comment: can't check for now, since it's already 02:00 '__') will check in 10+ hours

Comment: aww , nice problem "cannot be checked everytime"  -> you can just set your time manually and then use `ntpdate` or `ntpdate-debian` https://askubuntu.com/questions/679988/how-to-change-ubuntus-server-date-and-time-via-command-line